# Adding SDK to VS 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

This may be trip down memory lane. I have been asked to fix some code that was written 8 years ago. That in itself is OK. I have a Win 7 64 bit PC. As I now use VS2012 I had to install 2005 luckily had a copy still. Then all the updates from MS so that it will work with Win 7 64 bit. Create a dummy MFC app to make sure it all works. So far so good. Next I get the SDK to target the code to it is running on a Moxa UC7124 ARM4i. I get UC712XCE_SDK_V2.0.msi and install it.

Now the problem starts. I cannot see the Moxa platform inside VS2005. If I load the solution it comes up with the platform but skips compile. My guess is that VS cannot find the SDK. I have tried many things but obviously not the correct thing yet, I checked for environment variables and find none, registry has no entries.

I look inside Tools | Options under Projects and Solutions VC++ directories but cannot find the platform I only get Win32. So for the first time in a while at the moment I am lost. Has anyone got any ideas why I cannot get the Moxa SDK visible inside VS2005?

Comment: Honestly, It is unclear what you are asking, please rewrite the question!

Answer (score 0):

After several days progress has been made ....... but not yet fully working. My view was that there must be some permissions issue in Win 7 when trying to load older SDK's, so I uninstalled the SDK first. Next I right click on the SDK's msi and in security tick "run as compatibility" and choose "Previous version of Windows". I can now target my solution correctly. So this part appears to be working now and next I have to fix all the compile/linking issues. Still got a big hill to climb but fingers crossed when I get to deploy this that it is all going to work OK.